# Size classes and the initial view controller

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, size-classes

I am moving my Storyboard to use Auto Layout, and want to use size classes so I don't have to do the iPhone and iPad storyboard separate. But while 90% of the storyboard is the same, for the iPhone I use a navigation controller, while for the iPad I don't (load view manually and pop them on top of the main view).

Is there a easy way with size classes to specify that the initial view controller is different for the bigger sizes?